# Build a site from Scratch or with a platform

Tags: language-agnostic

I know the question was asked before but I'm still not sure.
I'm comfortable with php, mysql, jquery, html, css, etc.
Recently someone propose a collaboration where I help him to build a website where people search for jobs(in my country). He wants the website to offer possibility for uploading video. He doesn't really know but he want the site to be build on a platform, because he says its faster.
What do you think?

I can do it from scratch, but is he right? What do you suggest?
Also the part with the video I'm not really sure in what direction to go? What to use when you want to give a user possibility to upload a video(besides something like youtube)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHPmotion Media Sharing CMS aka PHPmotion](http://phpmotion.com/) is one of the most famous scripts to create a "youtube clone" site and it's free.

There are other options, check [The Top 5 Free YouTube Clone Scripts](http://blog.cirtex.com/2009/05/29/the-top-5-free-youtube-clone-scripts/) article, it might help you choose the best one for you.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is the way you feel most comfortable with.

Uploading video is not something as easy as it looks. There are a lot of things beyond the "upload". For example, video files are big. So you have to have a huge distributed storage system to store them. That alone would be quite a big task if you don't already have a "platform" that already does it for you.

So my suggestion is, talk him out of the video feature, then do the rest with your own way. : )

Comment: I would still want some answers with the video upload isue, what people use in this situations?

Comment: Alqin, to answer your question about what people use for video uploading --- they develop their own. And this is not something you as a single developer want to get into. Pretty much all YouTube does is video uploading and sharing and it's worth billions. Unless you have a dedicated team with millions of investment there is no chance it will work out for you. It’s much more complicated than just letting user upload files.

Comment: To give you another example, somebody uploaded a video from their Mac. The video is in Apple QuickTime format. Now another person who uses PC wants to watch this video but he does not have QuickTime installed, how is he going to watch it? You never run into such problems with YouTube because YouTube transcodes videos for you. If you don’t do that, nobody will use your site because they would run into problems viewing your video all the time.